# Custom Validator Test - Contains Errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, unit-testing, minitest

Wrote a custom validator in my rails project and want to write a test for when `nil` is passed into the record.

**The validator code**

```ruby
class FutureValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    if value == nil
      record.errors[attribute] << "can't be nil"
    elsif value <= Time.now
      record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "can't be in the past!")
    end
  end
end
```

**Possible test**

```
test "future validator rejects nil values" do
  @obj.future = nil
  assert_includes @obj.errors
end
```

I'd like to not only write a test that checks that `assert_not @obj.valid?` but actually demonstrate that the error message is being passed back. If that's asking too much I'll settle for knowing that an error message is coming back but currently my test isn't working.

It is returning

> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2..3)

**Update**
Getting close to a green test

```
  test "future validator rejects nil values" do
    @obj.future = nil
    @obj.valid?
    assert_includes @obj.errors.messages, {future: ["can't be nil"]}
  end
```

Is returning

> FutureValidatorTest#test_future_validator_rejects_nil_values [/Users/rwdonnard/WorkSpace/charter-pay-api/test/models/future_validator_test.rb:42]:
>   Expected {:future=>["can't be nil"]} to include {:future=>["can't be nil"]}.

Comment: How're you using it?  Can you post the model code where it calls it.  I don't really get why you check if the value is nil, you're reimplementing the presence validator.  You could remove that part and use `validates :date, presence: true, future: true`

Comment: @j-dexx pardon my ignorance but would `presence: true` provide a verbose/human-readable error message that they had passed `nil`?

Comment: the default message is "can't be blank"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue seems to be the way you test your class and most probably the exception gets raised from `assert_includes`. `assert_includes` expects at least 2 arguments with the first being a collection and the second being the object you expect to be included, in your case an array of errors and the error you expect respectively. Also your test is going to fail if you don't populate the `@obj.errors` collection, something that requires to call `@obj.valid?`

Your test should look like this:

```ruby
test "future validator rejects nil values" do
  @obj.future = nil
  @obj.valid?
  assert_includes @obj.errors.messages, { future: ["can't be nil"] }
end
```

This way you make sure that your model is invalid if `future.nil?` regardless of other validations in place.

---

I'd also suggest that you don't check for presence in your custom validator since Rails already provide a way for this. You could have your validator look like this:

```ruby
class FutureValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    if value <= Time.now
      record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "can't be in the past!")
    end
  end
end
```

and setup validation in your model like this:

```ruby
class SomeClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :future, presence: true, future: true
end
```

You could also simplify your tests like:

```ruby
test "is invalid with nil future date" do
  @obj.future = nil
  @obj.valid?
  assert_includes @obj.errors.messages[:future], "can't be nil"
end

test "future validator rejects past dates" do
  @obj.future = Date.new(1987, 1, 1)
  @obj.valid?
  assert_includes @obj.errors.messages[:future], "can't be in the past!"
end
```

Comment: That makes sense. When I run the code, though, I'm getting the following error. `Expected #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fe10ac663d8 @base=#<FutureValidatorable:0x007fe10ac66450 @future=nil, @validation_context=nil, @errors=#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fe10ac663d8 ...>>, @messages={:future=>["can't be nil"]}> to include {:future=>["can't be nil"]}.`

Comment: I think you should be checking against `@object.errors.messages` because `@object.errors` is not a collection but an instance of  the  `ActiveModel::Errors` class. I'll update the code to reflect this.

Comment: When I change it from `assert_includes` to `assert_equal` I got what I expected. Is this a fair answer?

Comment: `assert_equals` means that there will always be one error, the one for `future`. If you have other validations in place and you do not setup your object properly you'll end up having more than one error and your test will fail. I think `assert_includes` is more robust in this case.